# github pages not processing my style sheet

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Couldn't include second scss file in github page,the code is given below

the default layout "default.html" :

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/custom.css?v=' | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/index.css?v=' | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}"> 
</head>
```

custom.scss is included but index.scss throws 404 error

repository [link](https://github.com/Maghil/Maghil.github.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : add triple dash line like below at the start of a scss file

```
---
---
```

Cause of problem:

Since it's a scss file it must be processed by jekyll first,by adding three hyphens to the start of the file jekyll identifies the file to be processed

[source](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/)